# How to get ANY ionic2 project to run on ANY iPhone simulator ? (from osX El Capitan)

Tags: osx-elcapitan, simulator, wsod

My attempts to run the Ionic2 blank template on osX El Capitan, deploying to iPhone-SE, 10.2 simulator or iPhone 7 Plus always result in
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
followed by the "white screen of death"

So I tried Apache Cordova WKWebView plugin, with the same result, but got an additional error:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" for ios
Error: The header content contains invalid characters
```

I have an Ionic2 app published in the Android App Store, so my problems may be entirely to do with osX.

My most recent (failed) attempt in a Terminal:

```
cd /Users/apple/Desktop/don/ionic2
ionic start Test blank --v2
cd Test
ionic platform add ios
ionic prepare ios
ionic emulate ios --consolelogs
```

---> "white screen of death"

```
ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
ionic plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git --save



-> Installing "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" for ios
-> Error: The header content contains invalid characters ionic prepare ios

LAUNCH XCODE from/Users/apple/Desktop/don/ionic2/Test/platform/ios/.xcodeproj
In xCode: Run on simulator
```

---> "white screen of death"

How to get *any* ionic2 project to run on *any* iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this problem by purchasing a used Mac Mini for this job.
With this Mac, running OS x Sierra, I had no problems at all. The Blank app ran ok on an iPhone simulator. Even my app ran without errors.

It appears there was something unusual about my attempts to use a borrowed Mac for the purpose.

If you encounter the problem, take heart, there is at least this (drastic) way out.